# Performing a LIKE comparison on an INT field

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm fairly new to SQL and I was trying to get a full list of products that match a user input of a productID. Something like:

```
SELECT ProductID, ProductName FROM Products WHERE ProductID LIKE '%15%'
```

I would like it to list out all the matching products such as:
15, 150, 2154, etc

Unfortunately I'm running into problems because the productID field is an INT and not a string. Is there some relatively simple way around this?

Comment: If the "correct" answer is to convert/cast the value to text then the table should be altered to convert the column to text permanently. This is intuitive because you shouldn't need to perform mathematics on product identifiers.

Comment: onedaywhen is absolutely correct -- but I still think this is a useful SO question. Sometimes us engineers get asked to do things that are a bad idea, and it's valuable to be able to confirm that it's a bad idea for exactly the reason you thought.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can [`CAST`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html) the field to a string:

```
 ... WHERE CAST(ProductID as CHAR) LIKE '%15%'
```

this is very bad for performance, as mySQL can't make use of any indexes it's created for the INT column. But then, `LIKE` is always slow, even when done on a varchar field: There's no way to have an index that speeds up a LIKE query.

It might be worth having a second `varchar` column that mirrors the `int` column's values and doing the LIKE on that one - you'd have to benchmark to find out whether it'll do any good.

Comment: Is using CAST faster than using CONVERT?

Comment: @Maxx  they're synonyms of the same function, so there is no difference.

Comment: {"The expression contains undefined function call CAST()."} is what I'm seeing :(

Comment: @Maxx `SELECT ProductID, ProductName FROM Products WHERE CAST(ProductID as CHAR) LIKE '%15%'` should work.

Comment: It works in SQL Server Manager, but not in my C# code for some reason... then again SELECT ProductID FROM Products WHERE ProductID LIKE '%15%'  works in SQL server manager as well. I'm confused :/

Comment: Perhaps there is something that I'm not understanding about how this program is using the table adapters.

Comment: SQL Server Manager? So is this on SQL Server or MySQL? Also, post your C# code.

Comment: Yeah, you tagged this `mysql` so our solutions are related to mySQL. Is it something else?

Comment: It's a whole lot of code to post, It's all over the place in several different classes. I suppose I should just track down the guy who wrote it. I appreciate the help, however. This should give me enough to go on.

Answer (score 8):

You can [convert](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-convert.html) int to string using `CONVERT(ProductID, CHAR(16)) AS ProductID` and then use `LIKE`. So in your case it would be

```
SELECT ProductID, ProductName FROM Products
WHERE CONVERT(ProductID, CHAR(16)) LIKE '%15%'
```

You should remember that the query will make a full table scan without any support from indices. As a result it will be really expensive and time consuming.

Comment: {"The expression contains undefined function call CHAR()."} is what I'm seeing.

Comment: Which MySQL version are you using?