# Output $post value in a like operator

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How could i assign  the $post value to be the operator like.

This is working well to pass $post data to a sql query. Data is sendt by input 
 in a form. This is working but trying to change the $postvalue to be fetch as like operator.

Thinking something like this: '%thepostvalue%'

```
 $id= $_POST['id'];

        $this->orderid  = DB::query( 'SELECT orderid FROM production_table WHERE id = ?', $id  )->fetchSingle();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

concatenate "%" with your variable. Example

```
<?php

$id= $_POST['id'];
$id = "%".$id."%";
$this->orderid  = DB::query( 'SELECT orderid FROM production_table WHERE id like ?', $id  )->fetchSingle();
```

Comment: In most systems ID would be an integer field and you cannot do a like on an integer. I would suggest also look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8422455/performing-a-like-comparison-on-an-int-field if you are going to use this

Comment: That's why I have written `example` word. I don't know the field name of table So I put ID as it is. So that OP can get idea from this @mic