# Using comparison and like together to get results from table

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-data-jpa

given below is my table structure

```
Mobile_Number_Start  | Mobile_Number_End 
005555               | 006565
016565               | 017575
018585               | 019595
```

Now I have to search record depending on if user enter mobile number start or end. He can also enter number in either of column but not complete number

Suppose if user enters `01`  the record table will show output as

```
Mobile_Number_Start | Mobile_Number_End 
016565              | 017575
018585              | 019595
```

So for this I can't create a query that works 
Here is what my query looks like

```
Select * from table_name where mobile_number_start is less than  value entered in start and mobile_number_end is greater than value in mobilenumberend
```

I have carried out this operation using findall function of repository by building a specification builder class and passin the specification in

```
findAll(specification)
```

I need help in writing query for when user enters a part of mobile number but not complete number

Comment: Probably this query could fit your needs: `@Query(value = "select * from table where CONVERT(column_name1, CHAR(50)) like '%' + ?1 + '%' or  CONVERT(column_name2, CHAR(50)) like '%' + ?1 + '%'",
            nativeQuery = true)
    List<EntityPojo> custom(String str);`

Answer (score 0):

you can use the **LIKE** operator on your query

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name 
WHERE mobile_number_start LIKE '01%' and mobile_number_end LIKE '%01'
```

Comment: There is no way to apply *like* for integer values. At first, values need to be converted to numbers explicitly. Please take a look at this one [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8422455/performing-a-like-comparison-on-an-int-field). I think `string` is a solution to such kind of problem

Comment: oh yeah i totally forgot about that, thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM table_name 
 WHERE CAST(mobile_number_start as CHAR) LIKE '01%' 
 and CAST(mobile_number_end as CHAR) LIKE '%01'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like operator for comparison,

```
        SELECT * FROM table  WHERE start_number LIKE '1%' and end_number  LIKE '%1';
```